# How to serve (PDF,binary) file from GAS web to a browser?

Tags: google-apps-script

My Google Application Script creates PDF file. The I want to let user to download it. I wanted to make it easier for every one so I thought web application would be great choice. So I started to google for solution but I was not able to find anything userful.

Ideally I want to have form where web user enters a code that triggers PDF file creation (that part is ready - the PDF sits in Google Drive) and then the file is downloaded to end user computer via web browser.

**Is that possible via web created in Google Application Script?**

From this answer I found that what I am looking for is not possible https://stackoverflow.com/a/36701196/250422

The closest solution I found is [google-web-app-script-to-auto-download-from-google-drive](https://sodocumentation.net/google-apps-script/topic/8212/google-web-app-script-to-auto-download-from-google-drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to make users download a PDF file with the user's browser.
- You want to achieve this using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, the PDF file is converted to the data URL, and it makes users download as a PDF file using the browser.

### Sample script:

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor as `Code.gs`. And, please set the file ID of the PDF file. And, [please deploy Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}

function createDataUrl() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the PDF file you want to make user download.
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  return {
    data: `data:${file.getMimeType()};base64,${Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes())}`,
    filename: file.getName(),
  };
}
```

#### HTML&Javascript side: `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor as `index.html`.

```
<input type="button" value="download" onclick="download()" />
<script>
  function download() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(({ data, filename }) => {
        if (data && filename) {
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.download = filename;
          a.href = data;
          a.click();
        }
      })
      .createDataUrl();
  }
</script>
```

- In this case, when you access to the deployed Web Apps and click the button of "download" using your browser, the PDF file is downloaded to your local PC.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Downloading Active Sheet in Google Spreadsheet as CSV and PDF file by Clicking Button](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/11/23/downloading-active-sheet-in-google-spreadsheet-as-csv-and-pdf-file-by-clicking-button/)

  - This sample script in this answer is from above post.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you for that. How big could be the file?

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `How big could be the file?`, in my experience, I confirmed that the zip file of 20 MB can be downloaded using this script. But when the size is 30 MB, an error occurred. I apologize for this.

Comment: is that 30MB Google or web browser limitation?

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. About `is that 30MB Google or web browser limitation?`, I think that it might be due to the browser because at Google Apps Script, the maximum blob size is 50 MB. But, this is just my guess. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.