# Problems downloading base64 as pdf JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Apps Script Web App, I'm facing a problem.

From server side I return the base64 encoded html code of a page:

```
function getRAW() { 
  var formText = 'https://www.google.com/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formText);
  var pdf1 = response.getAs('application/pdf');
  //var myNewFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdf1);
  var blob = response.getBlob()
  var bytes = blob.getBytes();
  var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
  return encoded
}
```

And that works well.
Now, from client side, I want to download the base64 (is an html RAW content) as a pdf file (or .html if it is possible), but If I try to do like this I obtain a blank pdf page

```
function downloadRAW() {
  var encoded = window.value;
  var element = document.createElement('a');

  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + encoded);
  element.setAttribute('download', 'prova');
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Note that If I try to obtain a `text/plain;base64,` works perfectly (return a .txt) file; but this is not what I want.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: PDF's are binary files, not base64 encoded

Comment: @freefaller So I suppose that I can not do that...
If I return pdf1 (first part of the code) to the client, are there any way to make it downloadable? (It is a blob in application/pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know anything about App Scripts, but when I deal with binary files (from a server-side .Net application) I set header values to include "attachment". Probably worth checking the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) in particular the `download` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the proposed solution by @Tanaike is very good, I do not want to use additional permission on writing file in the Google Drive of the user (since my script is executed as "Run as user"), so I decided to use [JsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

Client-side code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

function downloadRAWPDF() {
    // window.value is a global variable that contains base64 encoded content (passed from server)
    var encoded = window.value;
    var decoded = atob(encoded);
    
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    // Resize text to fit in an A4 page
    var splitTitle = doc.splitTextToSize(decoded, 270);
    var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    doc.setFontType("normal");
    doc.setFontSize("11");
    var y = 7;
    for (var i = 0; i < splitTitle.length; i++) {                
        if (y > 280) {
            y = 10;
            doc.addPage();
        }
        doc.text(15, y, splitTitle[i]);
        y = y + 7;
    }

    doc.save('myPDF.pdf');
}
```

Server-side code (Google Apps Script):

```
// @return RAW Response base64 encoded (without response headers)
function getRAW(formObject) { 
  // contains the value of an Input Field
  var formText = formObject.myInput;
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formText);
  var blob = response.getBlob()
  var bytes = blob.getBytes();
  var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
  
  return encoded
}
```

To convert the file in a html file the approach suggested by @Tanaike is perfect: `data:text/html;base64, + encoded`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to convert the HTML data to a PDF data as the raw HTML code.

  - From `I want to download the base64 (is an html RAW content) as a pdf file`, I thought that the PDF data has the raw HTML code.
- You want to make users download the HTML data as a PDF file.
- `var encoded = window.value;` of your Javascript side is the value of `encoded` from the function of `getRAW()` of Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, in order to convert the raw HTML code (text data) to a PDF data, I would like to propose to use the Google Document. When Google Document is used, the text data can be converted to the PDF data.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify `getRAW()` at Google Apps Script side as follows.

```
function downloadRAW() {
  var formText = 'https://www.google.com/';
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formText).getContentText();
  var doc = DocumentApp.create("temp");
  doc.getBody().editAsText().setText(html);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  var blob = file.getBlob();
  var bytes = blob.getBytes();
  var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
  file.setTrashed(true);
  return encoded
}
```

- In this modification, at first, the retrieved HTML data is put to the Google Document created as a temporal document, and then, the Google Document is converted to the PDF data and converted to the base64 data, and return the data. And, the temporal Document is removed.

#### Note:

- From `(or .html if it is possible)`, if you want to export it as the text file, how about the following modification?

  - Google Apps Script side:

    ```
      function downloadRAW() {
        var formText = 'https://www.google.com/';
        var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formText).getBlob().setContentType("text/html");
        var bytes = blob.getBytes();
        var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
        return encoded
      }
    ```
  - Javascript side:

    - In this case, please modify `element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + encoded);` as follows.

      ```
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;base64,' + encoded);
      ```
- From your question, I couldn't understand about the method for giving the value of `encoded` of Google Apps Script side to `var encoded = window.value;` of Javascript side. So if you want to see the sample script for this. I thought that this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67545478/7108653)
- When the blob of HTML is converted to `application/json`, the raw HTML code cannot be retrieved. The rendered result is obtained. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [create(name) of Class DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#createname)
- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose())
- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have found some workaround using libraries to achieve what I want, I will post here the solution.

Your proposed solution is good, the way of using Google Docs to save and convert it to a PDF is very smart!

I have used window.value like a global variable in theJavascript client-side code, I'm currently searching for some workaround

Comment: @Fabio Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize again. But, I think that my approach might be useful for other users. So, in this case, I would like to leave my answer.

Comment: Do not worry, your approach is very good and smart and your reply is so detailed, someone can take advantage of it so leave your answer. Thank you again for your help!