# Apps Script => HTMLService to PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a dynamic spellbook for my dnd players, so i have a sheet with all the spells and data, i have it in html, but somehow i cannot make it pdf with the "getAs('application/pdf');" command.

Any help?

```
function doGet() {
  var actualSpreadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets=actualSpreadSheet.getSheets();

  var spellsSheet;
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.getName()=="LibroConjuros"){
      spellsSheet=sheet;
    }
  });

  var spellBook=spellsSheet.getRange("C2:AE9").getValues();
  spellBook.forEach(function(spell){
    if(spell[2]!=''){
      spellsData.push(spell);
    }
  });
  
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Card').evaluate().getAs('application/pdf');

  return html;
}
```

It shows an html as long as i dont use the getAs, but, printing from html is horrible and it gets cropped everytime

I'm looking for some way to convert from html to pdf, so i can print the cards im making

Comment: First, in the case of `doGet`, the objects of HtmlService.HtmlOutput or ContentService.TextOutput can be returned. I think that your script of `var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Card').evaluate().getAs('application/pdf');` returns a Blob of PDF data. But, `return html;` cannot be used. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue. But, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation from your question, and I cannot propose a modified script. So, I pointed out only the reason for your current issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Probably you have to expose a downloadable link or a button instead of the direct PDF output. Look at the similar code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545478/how-to-serve-pdf-binary-file-from-gas-web-to-a-browser).